# How to convert .xml bank statement to .csv tex file, using VB.net?

Tags: xml, vb.net, csv

I would like to convert a bank statement in .xml file, to a more eyes friendly .csv file.

The .xml file has so many nodes and sub nodes, and I cant seem to find how to read many sublevels inside nodes.

I would need to use a Visual Studio 2012 with VB.net for that..

I have tried several examples, but as a novice I can't really make it work.

Thanks for all sugestions!

edit:

Hi! I have prepared the sample to post, but somehow forgot to paste it in my post...

Exsample xml bank statement:

```
<Document
    xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <BkToCstmrStmt>
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>MSGSTMT1234567890123457890</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>2019-02-13T17:17:18.2369252+01:00</CreDtTm>
        </GrpHdr>
        <Stmt>
            <Id>SKBSTMT5/2019-EUR</Id>
            <LglSeqNb>20195</LglSeqNb>
            <CreDtTm>2019-01-01T00:00:00</CreDtTm>
            <Acct>
                <Id>
                    <IBAN>DE012345678901234</IBAN>
                </Id>
                <Ownr>
                    <Nm>COMPANY NAME</Nm>
                    <PstlAdr>
                        <Ctry>DE</Ctry>
                        <AdrLine>ADDRESS 1</AdrLine>
                        <AdrLine>ADDRESS 2</AdrLine>
                    </PstlAdr>
                </Ownr>
                <Svcr>
                    <FinInstnId>
                        <BIC>BICCODE</BIC>
                        <Nm>BANK NAME</Nm>
                        <PstlAdr>
                            <Ctry>DE</Ctry>
                        </PstlAdr>
                    </FinInstnId>
                </Svcr>
            </Acct>
            <Bal>
                <Tp>
                    <CdOrPrtry>
                        <Cd>OPBD</Cd>
                    </CdOrPrtry>
                </Tp>
                <Amt Ccy="EUR">11000.10</Amt>
                <CdtDbtInd>CRDT</CdtDbtInd>
                <Dt>
                    <Dt>2019-01-01</Dt>
                </Dt>
            </Bal>
            <Bal>
                <Tp>
                    <CdOrPrtry>
                        <Cd>CLBD</Cd>
                    </CdOrPrtry>
                </Tp>
                <Amt Ccy="EUR">1000.10</Amt>
                <CdtDbtInd>CRDT</CdtDbtInd>
                <Dt>
                    <Dt>2019-01-01</Dt>
                </Dt>
            </Bal>
            <TxsSummry>
                <TtlCdtNtries>
                    <NbOfNtries>2</NbOfNtries>
                    <Sum>11000.10</Sum>
                </TtlCdtNtries>
                <TtlDbtNtries>
                    <NbOfNtries>12</NbOfNtries>
                    <Sum>11111.11</Sum>
                </TtlDbtNtries>
            </TxsSummry>
            <Ntry>
                <Amt Ccy="EUR">11.11</Amt>
                <CdtDbtInd>CRDT</CdtDbtInd>
                <Sts>BOOK</Sts>
                <BookgDt>
                    <Dt>2019-01-01</Dt>
                </BookgDt>
                <ValDt>
                    <Dt>2019-01-01</Dt>
                </ValDt>
                <AcctSvcrRef>111111111111</AcctSvcrRef>
                <BkTxCd>
                    <Prtry>
                        <Cd>PP03</Cd>
                    </Prtry>
                </BkTxCd>
                <NtryDtls>
                    <TxDtls>
                        <Refs>
                            <InstrId>12345678901</InstrId>
                            <EndToEndId>NOTPROVIDED</EndToEndId>
                            <TxId>1234567890123456</TxId>
                        </Refs>
                        <RltdPties>
                            <Dbtr>
                                <Nm>DEBITOR NAME</Nm>
                                <PstlAdr>
                                    <Ctry>DE</Ctry>
                                </PstlAdr>
                            </Dbtr>
                            <DbtrAcct>
                                <Id>
                                    <IBAN>DE012345678901234</IBAN>
                                </Id>
                            </DbtrAcct>
                            <Cdtr>
                                <Nm>CREDITOR NAME</Nm>
                                <PstlAdr>
                                    <Ctry>DE</Ctry>
                                </PstlAdr>
                            </Cdtr>
                            <CdtrAcct>
                                <Id>
                                    <IBAN>DE098765432109874</IBAN>
                                </Id>
                            </CdtrAcct>
                        </RltdPties>
                        <RltdAgts>
                            <DbtrAgt>
                                <FinInstnId>
                                    <BIC>BICCODE</BIC>
                                </FinInstnId>
                            </DbtrAgt>
                            <CdtrAgt>
                                <FinInstnId>
                                    <BIC>BICCODE</BIC>
                                </FinInstnId>
                            </CdtrAgt>
                        </RltdAgts>
                        <Purp>
                            <Prtry>OTHR</Prtry>
                        </Purp>
                        <RmtInf>
                            <Ustrd>PAYMENT</Ustrd>
                        </RmtInf>
                    </TxDtls>
                </NtryDtls>
            </Ntry>
            <Ntry>
                <Amt Ccy="EUR">2000.20</Amt>
                <CdtDbtInd>DBIT</CdtDbtInd>
                <Sts>BOOK</Sts>
                <BookgDt>
                    <Dt>2019-01-02</Dt>
                </BookgDt>
                <ValDt>
                    <Dt>2019-01-02</Dt>
                </ValDt>
                <AcctSvcrRef>9876543210</AcctSvcrRef>
                <BkTxCd>
                    <Prtry>
                        <Cd>US03</Cd>
                    </Prtry>
                </BkTxCd>
                <NtryDtls>
                    <TxDtls>
                        <Refs>
                            <InstrId>987654321</InstrId>
                            <EndToEndId>DE987654</EndToEndId>
                            <TxId>898765432109876543210</TxId>
                        </Refs>
                        <RltdPties>
                            <Dbtr>
                                <Nm>DEBITOR NAME</Nm>
                                <PstlAdr>
                                    <Ctry>DE</Ctry>
                                </PstlAdr>
                            </Dbtr>
                            <DbtrAcct>
                                <Id>
                                    <IBAN>DE098765432109874</IBAN>
                                </Id>
                            </DbtrAcct>
                            <Cdtr>
                                <Nm>CREDITOR NAME</Nm>
                                <PstlAdr>
                                    <Ctry>DE</Ctry>
                                    <AdrLine>ADDRESS 3</AdrLine>
                                    <AdrLine>ADDRESS 4</AdrLine>
                                </PstlAdr>
                            </Cdtr>
                            <CdtrAcct>
                                <Id>
                                    <IBAN>DE12345678901234</IBAN>
                                </Id>
                            </CdtrAcct>
                        </RltdPties>
                        <RltdAgts>
                            <DbtrAgt>
                                <FinInstnId>
                                    <BIC>BICCODE</BIC>
                                </FinInstnId>
                            </DbtrAgt>
                            <CdtrAgt>
                                <FinInstnId>
                                    <BIC>BICCODE</BIC>
                                </FinInstnId>
                            </CdtrAgt>
                        </RltdAgts>
                        <Purp>
                            <Prtry>PRCP</Prtry>
                        </Purp>
                        <RmtInf>
                            <Strd>
                                <CdtrRefInf>
                                    <Tp>
                                        <CdOrPrtry>
                                            <Cd>SCOR</Cd>
                                        </CdOrPrtry>
                                    </Tp>
                                    <Ref>123446789</Ref>
                                </CdtrRefInf>
                                <AddtlRmtInf>PAYMENT INFO</AddtlRmtInf>
                            </Strd>
                        </RmtInf>
                    </TxDtls>
                </NtryDtls>
            </Ntry>
        </Stmt>
    </BkToCstmrStmt>
</Document>
```

With use of  RobertBaron's advice and the following code, I was able to get some information out of xml file.

```
If element.Name.LocalName.ToString() = "EndToEndId" Then
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\cvs.csv", element.Value.ToString & ", ", True)
End If
```

It works great on simple xml files.

But, how can I find data embedded deeper in the nodes structure?

For example, how would I get to:

Creditor's account number (iban), that is buried deep inside the structure:

```
<Document xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02">
    <BkToCstmrStmt>
        <Stmt>
            <Ntry>
                <NtryDtls>
                    <TxDtls>
                        <CdtrAcct>
                            <Id>
                                <IBAN>
```

Thanks for the input!

Comment: Could you update your question with what you have tried so far along with the specific issues you are getting?

Comment: You need to post samples.  Each xml is different so there is no generic method that will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that will get you started. Load the XML file in memory, and then use LINQ to select the nodes you want.

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("test.xml")
        Dim elements As IEnumerable(Of XElement)

        ' Select all nodes in the XML file.
        elements = doc.Descendants()

        ' Select only leaf nodes.
        elements = doc.Descendants.Where(Function(element) element.HasElements = False)

        ' etc...

        ' Loop through selected nodes, and write to .csv the values you want.
        For Each element As XElement In elements
            Debug.WriteLine(element.Name.LocalName + ": " + If(element.Value = Nothing, "", element.Value))
        Next

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice! It appears I a some special kind of stupid, but I just cant find a way to extract a single value; for example bank number that is between tags:  <IBAN></IBAN> and just write it into, lets say, a textbox. I have tried     texbox.text = element.Element("IBAN").Value.toString(), but unfortunately with no luck...

Comment: @tj6006 - I updated my answer to show how to print in the immediate window element names and values.

Comment: Hi again! I have managed to get an output with name and value in each line of a texbox, using this: textbox.Text = textbox.Text + element.Name.LocalName.ToString + ": " + element.Value.ToString & Environment.NewLine; but since I do not need all information from the xml, I would like to extract just some of the data - how do I get to print only lets say date and iban number in each line?

Comment: @tj6006 - You can use `If` statements to take only what you want. Note, my answer was just to get you started. Your question is currently on hold because it is not specific enough. You should accept this answer, and post a new question with the code you have, and a description of what you want to extract exactly, that is, how you want your csv file to look like.